# Get the second highest sample date

Tags: sql, sql-server, greatest-n-per-group

I am trying to get second highest sample date and get the following error, please let me know where am i doing it wrong

```
(SELECT* FROM resheader WHERE sampledate =
   (SELECT MAX(sampleDate) FROM resheader 
      WHERE sampleDate < (SELECT MAX(sampleDate) FROM resheader)
   )
) as 'Previous Sample'
```

Error

> Msg 116, Level 16, State 1, Line 12 Only one expression can be
>   specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with
>   EXISTS.

Comment: Are you using MySQL?  Now that I think of it, the error message looks a bit more like SLQ Server.

Comment: mssql or mysql? If mssql then which version?

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server 2012 you can use use the [`OFFSET FETCH`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg699618(v=sql.110).aspx) clause to get the second row (after sorting by desired criteria):

```
SELECT * FROM resheader 
ORDER BY sampledate DESC
OFFSET 1 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY
```

Answer (score 0):

How about doing this?  If we assume that all the dates are unique:

```
SELECT rh.*
FROM resheader rh
ORDER BY sampleDate DESC
LIMIT 1, 1;
```

If they are not unique, then:

```
SELECT rh.*
FROM resheader rh
WHERE sampledate = (SELECT DISTINCT SampleDate
                    FROM resheader
                    ORDER BY sampleDate DESC
                    LIMIT 1, 1
                   );
```

Answer (score 0):

If your SQL Server version doesn't support `FETCH OFFSET` (2012 and versions above). You can use ranking functions to achieve that:

```
SELECT T.sampledate 
FROM (
    SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY sampledate DESC) AS RN, *
    FROM resheader
    ) AS T
WHERE T.RN = 2;
```